# Error in Log Cat

Tags: java, android, exception, fatal-error

Hi I am new in programming and I have this error in Log Cat. Log Cat shows 'FATAL EXCEPTION Main' and my application has stopped unexpectedly.I am trying to deal with it from several days. Application supposed to show battery information

```
05-02 22:01:11.836: I/Process(521): Sending signal. PID: 521 SIG: 9
05-02 22:18:54.743: D/dalvikvm(550): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 1238 objects / 82472 bytes in 181ms
05-02 22:18:55.654: W/ResourceType(550): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000032
05-02 22:18:55.664: D/AndroidRuntime(550): Shutting down VM
05-02 22:18:55.664: W/dalvikvm(550): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
05-02 22:18:55.744: E/AndroidRuntime(550): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-02 22:18:55.744: E/AndroidRuntime(550): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {vader.batterydroid/vader.batterydroid.PageInfo}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x32
05-02 22:18:55.744: E/AndroidRuntime(550):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3128)
05-02 22:18:55.744: E/AndroidRuntime(550):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3143)
05-02 22:18:55.744: E/AndroidRuntime(550):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2684)
05-02 22:18:55.744: E/AndroidRuntime(550):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
05-02 22:18:55.744: E/AndroidRuntime(550):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
05-02 22:18:55.744: E/AndroidRuntime(550):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-02 22:18:55.744: E/AndroidRuntime(550):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-02 22:18:55.744: E/AndroidRuntime(550):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
05-02 22:18:55.744: E/AndroidRuntime(550):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-02 22:18:55.744: E/AndroidRuntime(550):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-02 22:18:55.744: E/AndroidRuntime(550):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
05-02 22:18:55.744: E/AndroidRuntime(550):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
05-02 22:18:55.744: E/AndroidRuntime(550):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-02 22:18:55.744: E/AndroidRuntime(550): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x32
05-02 22:18:55.744: E/AndroidRuntime(550):  at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:201)
05-02 22:18:55.744: E/AndroidRuntime(550):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2817)
05-02 22:18:55.744: E/AndroidRuntime(550):  at vader.batterydroid.PageInfo.updateViews(PageInfo.java:171)
05-02 22:18:55.744: E/AndroidRuntime(550):  at vader.batterydroid.PageInfo.updateInfo(PageInfo.java:77)
05-02 22:18:55.744: E/AndroidRuntime(550):  at vader.batterydroid.PageInfo.access$0(PageInfo.java:74)
05-02 22:18:55.744: E/AndroidRuntime(550):  at vader.batterydroid.PageInfo$BatteryInfoReceiver.onReceive(PageInfo.java:255)
05-02 22:18:55.744: E/AndroidRuntime(550):  at vader.batterydroid.PageInfo.onResume(PageInfo.java:242)
05-02 22:18:55.744: E/AndroidRuntime(550):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1149)
05-02 22:18:55.744: E/AndroidRuntime(550):  at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:3823)
05-02 22:18:55.744: E/AndroidRuntime(550):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3118)
05-02 22:18:55.744: E/AndroidRuntime(550):  ... 12 more
```

Here is my code:

```
package vader.batterydroid;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;   
import android.app.Activity;   
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;   
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.Date;

public class PageInfo extends Activity{
  private static final boolean DEBUG = false;
  private static final String NOT_AVAIABLE = "----";
  private static final String TAG = "PageInfo";
  private static final int TEMPERATURE_NOT_AVAILABLE = -9999;
  BatteryInfoReceiver mBatteryIR;
  java.text.DateFormat mDF;
  IconDrawer mDrawer;
  private int mHealth;
  private int mLevel;
  private SharedPreferences mPM;
  private int mPlugged;
  private boolean mPresent;
  private int mRemainingCapacity;
  private int mScale;
  private int mStatus;
  private String mTechnology;
  private int mTemperature;
  private long mUpdateTime;
  private int mVoltage;
  private Button mbtSettings;
  private ImageView mivGraph;
  private TextView mtvCap;
  private TextView mtvHealth;
  private TextView mtvLastUpdate;
  private TextView mtvPlugged;
  private TextView mtvPresent;
  private TextView mtvStatus;
  private TextView mtvTechnology;
  private TextView mtvTemperature;
  private TextView mtvVoltage;

  private void parseIntent(Intent paramIntent){
   this.mUpdateTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    this.mPresent = paramIntent.getBooleanExtra("present", false);
    this.mTechnology = paramIntent.getStringExtra("technology");
    this.mHealth = paramIntent.getIntExtra("health", 0);
    this.mStatus = paramIntent.getIntExtra("status", 0);
    this.mPlugged = paramIntent.getIntExtra("plugged", 0);
    this.mLevel = paramIntent.getIntExtra("level", 0);
    this.mScale = paramIntent.getIntExtra("scale", 0);
    this.mVoltage = paramIntent.getIntExtra("voltage", 0);
    this.mTemperature = paramIntent.getIntExtra("temperature", -9999);
    if (this.mScale > 0){
      this.mRemainingCapacity = (100 * this.mLevel / this.mScale);
      return;
    }
    this.mRemainingCapacity = this.mLevel;
  }

  private void updateInfo(Context paramContext, Intent paramIntent)
  {
    parseIntent(paramIntent);
    updateViews();
    updateWidgetDemo(paramIntent);
  }

  private void updateViews()
  {
    Object localObject1;
    Object localObject2;
    Object localObject3;
    if (this.mPresent)
    {
      this.mtvPresent.setText(getResources().getText(R.string.info_text_battery_present_yes));
      if (this.mTechnology == null)
      this.mtvTechnology.setText(this.mTechnology);

  switch (this.mHealth)
  {
  default:
    localObject1 = "----";
    this.mtvHealth.setText((CharSequence)localObject1);
    switch (this.mStatus)
    {
    default:
      localObject2 = "----";   
      this.mtvStatus.setText((CharSequence)localObject2);
      switch (this.mPlugged)
      {
      default:
        localObject3 = "----";
        this.mtvPlugged.setText((CharSequence)localObject3);
        if (this.mScale > 0)
        {
          this.mtvCap.setText(this.mRemainingCapacity + "% (" + this.mLevel + "/" + this.mScale + ")");
          this.mtvVoltage.setText(this.mVoltage + "mV");
          if (this.mTemperature > -9999)
            break;
          this.mtvTemperature.setText("----");
        }
        break;
      case 1:
      case 2:
      }
      break;
    case 1:
    case 2:
    case 3:
    case 4:
    case 5:
    }
    break;
  case 1:
  case 2:
  case 3:
  case 4:
  case 5:
  case 6:
  }
}
while (true)
{
  Date localDate = new Date(this.mUpdateTime);
  this.mtvLastUpdate.setText(this.mDF.format(localDate));
this.mtvPresent.setText(getResources().getText(R.string.info_text_battery_present_no));
  this.mtvTechnology.setText("----");
  localObject1 = getResources().getText(R.string.info_text_battery_health_unknown);
  localObject1 = getResources().getText(R.string.info_text_battery_health_good);
  localObject1 = getResources().getText(R.string.info_text_battery_health_overheat);
  localObject1 = getResources().getText(R.string.info_text_battery_health_dead);
  localObject1 = getResources().getText(R.string.info_text_battery_health_over_voltage);
  localObject1 = getResources().getText(R.string.info_text_battery_health_unspecified_failure);
  localObject2 = getResources().getText(R.string.info_text_battery_status_unknown);
  localObject2 = getResources().getText(R.string.info_text_battery_status_charging);
  localObject2 = getResources().getText(R.string.info_text_battery_status_discharging);
  localObject2 = getResources().getText(R.string.info_text_battery_status_not_charging);
  localObject2 = getResources().getText(R.string.info_text_battery_status_full);
  localObject3 = getResources().getText(R.string.info_text_battery_plugged_ac);
  localObject3 = getResources().getText(R.string.info_text_battery_plugged_usb);
  this.mtvCap.setText(this.mLevel);
  this.mtvTemperature.setText(this.mTemperature / 10 + "Â°C / " + (int)((320.0F + 9.0F * this.mTemperature / 5.0F) / 10.0F) + "Â°F");
    }
  }

  private void updateWidgetDemo(Intent paramIntent)
  {
    this.mDrawer.update(paramIntent);
        this.mivGraph.setImageBitmap(this.mDrawer.drawIcon(getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.workspaceicon_size), 1.0F));
  }

  @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.CUPCAKE) protected void onCreate(Bundle paramBundle)
  {
    this.mPM = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplication());
    if (Integer.parseInt(this.mPM.getString("ICON_STYLE", getResources().getString(R.string.icon_style_default))) == 0)
    {
      setTheme(R.style.Theme_Transparent);
      getWindow().setFlags(4, 4);
      setContentView(R.layout.page_info_android);
    }
    while (true)
    {
      this.mDrawer = new IconDrawer(this);
      this.mtvPresent = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.Present));
      this.mtvTechnology = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.Tech));
      this.mtvHealth = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.Health));
      this.mtvStatus = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.Status));
      this.mtvPlugged = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.Plugged));
      this.mtvCap = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.Cap));
      this.mtvVoltage = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.Voltage));
      this.mtvTemperature = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.Temp));
      this.mivGraph = ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivGraph));
      this.mtvLastUpdate = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvLastUpdate));
      this.mbtSettings = ((Button)findViewById(R.id.btSettings));
      this.mbtSettings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
  {
    public void onClick(View paramAnonymousView)
    {
      Intent localIntent = new Intent(PageInfo.this.getApplicationContext(), PrefSettings.class);
      PageInfo.this.startActivity(localIntent);
    }
  });
      this.mDF = android.text.format.DateFormat.getTimeFormat(getBaseContext());
      super.onCreate(paramBundle);
      setTheme(R.style.Theme_NoTitle);
      setContentView(R.layout.page_info);
      return;
    }
  }

  @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.CUPCAKE) protected void onPause()
  {
    this.mBatteryIR.unregisterReceiver();
    this.mBatteryIR = null;
    int[] arrayOfInt = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this).getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(this, WidgetProvider.class));
    if ((arrayOfInt != null) && (arrayOfInt.length > 0))
    {
      Intent localIntent = new Intent();
      localIntent.putExtra("appWidgetIds", arrayOfInt);
      localIntent.setAction(WidgetProvider.FORCE_WIDGET_UPDATE);
      sendBroadcast(localIntent);
    }
    super.onPause();
  }

  protected void onResume()
  {
    if (this.mBatteryIR == null)
      this.mBatteryIR = new BatteryInfoReceiver();
    Intent localIntent = this.mBatteryIR.registerReceiver();
    this.mBatteryIR.onReceive(getApplicationContext(), localIntent);
    super.onResume();
  }

  class BatteryInfoReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
  {
    BatteryInfoReceiver()
    {
    }

    public void onReceive(Context paramContext, Intent paramIntent)
    {
      if ("android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED".equals(paramIntent.getAction()))
        PageInfo.this.updateInfo(paramContext, paramIntent);
    }

    public Intent registerReceiver()
    {
      return PageInfo.this.getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(this, new     IntentFilter("android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED"));
    }

    public void unregisterReceiver()
    {
      PageInfo.this.getApplicationContext().unregisterReceiver(this);
    }
  }
}
```

I will be very thankful if anybody help me. :)

Comment: what is at line 171 in `PageInfo.java`?

Comment: @user2349694 Please make your post more readable and highlight the area where you are expecting the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.In eclipse, go to Project > Clean…

2.select your project, then press OK

3.relaunch the app

if it happens again delete the r.java file. it will generate automatically.

Hope this helps.

**Edit:-**

I think somewhere in your code you are try to setText() with some integer value. Please debug and you will notice this.

Try, **view.setText(Integer.toString(iSomeInteger))** instead.

Follow [this link for better clearity](http://android.konreu.com/developer-how-to/resources-notfoundexception/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is this issue been resolved. If yes, mark the relevant answer as correct for others to benifit

Answer (score 1):

```
private int mLevel;
//...
this.mtvCap.setText(this.mLevel);
```

`setText(int)` expects a resource identifier but `mLevel` isn't one. Use `setText(CharSequence)` instead, e.g.

```
this.mtvCap.setText(Integer.toString(this.mLevel));
```

Comment: Feel free to mark the answer as correct. When you have the reputation (15), you can also upvote helpful answers.